# Parse.com - How to refresh the User's information

Tags: ios, parse-platform

When I'm changing for example a bool in the Parse backend I can not retrieve this value in my iOS app. Please see the following screenshot where the first bool of the user object was changed manually and the second was changed from the app.

[image]

The first one does not work whereas the one (that was changed from the app) does work.
I'm getting the value with the following piece of code:

```
[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"is_pro"]
```

In the first case the return object is always `nil` (where I've changed the bool manually).

Comment: Refresh your [PFUser currentUser].

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After you've made changes to your user's Parse table, call

```
[[PFUser currentUser] fetch]; //synchronous
```

or

```
[[PFUser currentUser] fetchInBackground]; //asynchronous
```

or

```
[[PFUser currentUser] fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) { //asynchronous with completion block
```

before

```
[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"is_pro"]
```

to get an updated copy of your `[PFUser currentUser]` object.

Note: [`refresh`](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/refresh) and [`refreshInBackgroundWithBlock:`](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/refreshInBackgroundWithBlock:) are now deprecated and have been replaced with [`fetch`](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/fetch) and [`fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:`](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/refreshInBackgroundWithBlock:)

**Update:**

As Ryan Kreager pointed out in the comments, it's probably better/more efficient to use [`fetchIfNeeded`](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/fetchIfNeeded), [`fetchIfNeededInBackground`](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/fetchIfNeededInBackground), or [`fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:`](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:) "since they will use the local cache when available."

Comment: You once again saved me :)
However `refresh` is deprecated, so I've used `fetch` and that did the trick.

Comment: @user1463853 OK, cool. :) Didn't know it had been deprecated. I'll make the update. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't plan on making changes to the User object across multiple devices simultaneously, it's always a good idea to use `fetchifneededinbackgroundwithblock`, since it will use the local cache when available.

Comment: @RyanKreager That's true. I guess changing values in the database probably won't be a constant occurrence so it's probably better to fetch only if needed... I can add that as an addendum to my answer.

Comment: I tried fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock but dont get my updates. fetchInBackgroundWithBlock however works great.

Answer (score 2):

Examples in **Swift**:

First and foremost, please have a look at [`isDataAvailable`](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/isDataAvailable) and [`isDirty`](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/isDirty).

```
var user = PFUser.currentUser()!

// Gets whether the PFObject has been fetched.
// isDataAvailable: true if the PFObject is new or has been fetched or refreshed, otherwise false.
user.isDataAvailable()

// Gets whether any key-value pair in this object (or its children) has been added/updated/removed and not saved yet. 
// Returns whether this object has been altered and not saved yet.
user.isDirty()
```

Also it is probably better/more efficient to use [`fetchIfNeeded`](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/fetchIfNeeded), [`fetchIfNeededInBackground`](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/fetchIfNeededInBackground), or [`fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:`](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:) "since they will use the local cache when available."

```
// Synchronously fetches the PFObject data from the server if isDataAvailable is false.
user.fetchIfNeeded()

// Fetches the PFObject data asynchronously if isDataAvailable is false, then sets it as a result for the task.    
user.fetchIfNeededInBackground()

// Fetches the PFObject data asynchronously if isDataAvailable is false, then calls the callback block.        
user.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock({ 
            (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // Code here         
})
```

Otherwise you can also use [`fetch`](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/fetch), [`fetchInBackground`](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/fetchInBackground), [`fetchInBackgroundWithBlock`](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:) if you do not need to use the local cache.

```
// Synchronously fetches the PFObject with the current data from the server.
user.fetch()
            
// Fetches the PFObject asynchronously and sets it as a result for the task.
user.fetchInBackground()
            
// Fetches the PFObject asynchronously and executes the given callback block.
user.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({
               (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
     // Code here
})
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have pointers you can not use fetch. this is the best way:

```
 PFQuery *userQuery = [PFUser query];
    [userQuery includeKey:@"addresses"];
    [userQuery includeKey:@"cards"];
    [userQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
    [userQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * _Nullable object, NSError * _Nullable error) {
}];
```