# Parse.com Refresh User Info

Tags: macos, swift, parse-platform, refresh

I have written an iOS app that uses Parse.com. When I need to change the information about a user I use `refreshInBackgroundWithBlock`. I am now writing the app for Mac OS X but I do not seem to be able to use `refreshInBackgroundWithBlock`. Any Suggestions?

Here is the code below.

```
//Refresh the User Info
currentUser.refreshInBackgroundWithBlock { (object, error) -> Void in
//Fetch the User Info
currentUser.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock { (result, error) -> Void in
    //Check if the comments read is nil
    if object.objectForKey("commentsRead") === nil {
         println("Comments Read is empty")                     
    } else {                       
         var currentRead:[Int] = []
         //If not empty assign the array to the value
         currentRead = object.objectForKey("commentsRead") as Array
         currentRead.append(0)
         var user = PFUser.currentUser()
         user.setObject(currentRead, forKey: "commentsRead")
         user.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (result, error) -> Void in
         println("Completed!")
     }

}
```

Comment: What does Parse's documentation say?

Comment: It seems to be the same for iOS and OSX. On the Mac I am seeing `'PFUser' does not have a member named 'refreshInBackgroundWithBlock'`.

Comment: I'd highly recommend actually posting your actual code that's generating the error.

Comment: I have added the code above.

Comment: Refresh is deprecated, use fetch

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse.com - How to refresh the User's information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553621/parse-com-how-to-refresh-the-users-information)

Answer (score 2):

According to the parse doc, `refreshInBackgroundWithBlock` is deprecated and replaced  by `fetchInBackgroundWithBlock`  ([See this](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/refreshInBackgroundWithBlock:))

So you don't need to call `refreshInBackgroundWithBlock`.